# What is the defination of unbounded function except function which is not bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the defination of unbounded function except function which is not ?

Comment: That literally is what "unbounded" means. What is your question exactly? Whether there is an alternative definition which is phrased differently?

Comment: What is the definition of "defination"? Is it equivalent to "definition"? Ah, I see. [Here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100808022024AAvxhBj) is a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded if for every $M>0$, there exists $x\in X$ such that $|f(x)|>M$.

Comment: (+1), but note that "If for any..." is potentially ambiguous, meaning "If for every..." (as intended) or "If for some..." (as in "If for any reason...").

Comment: Good point. I changed it so as to avoid confusion.